# Problema con mi programa de cifrado

Tags: c++, linux

Este es mi programa:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char* llave = argv[1];
    int tamaño_llave = std::strlen(llave);
    char c;
    char c_cifrado;
    int i = 0;
    while (std::cin) {
        if (i == tamaño_llave) i = 0;
        std::cin >> c;
        c_cifrado = c^llave[i];
        std::cout << c_cifrado;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Cuando lo uso de la siguiente forma:

```
$ echo -n 'h' > mensaje_entrada.txt
$ ./11 asdf < mensaje_entrada.txt
```

Devuelve, como esperaba:

`$`

Una tabulación. Osea "tab_horizontal$" (con tab horizontal me refiero al carácter con código 9 en ascii)

Ahora bien cuando hago:

```
$ (./11 asdf < mensaje_entrada.txt) > mensaje_cifrado.txt
$ ./11 asdf < mensaje_cifrado.txt
```

En vez de darme lo que esperaría:

`h$`

Me da:

`zh$`

Entiendo de donde sale la "h" ahí. La esperaba totalmente:

```
c^llave[i]
    tab horizontal ^ a
    00001001
    01100001
    resultado = 1101000 = 104 en decimal ! perfecto, eso es lo que esperaba
```

¿ Pero de donde esta saliendo la "z" esa ?
Cuando hago `cat mensaje_codificado.txt` para ver si hay algo raro me encuentro nada más con la tabulación que esperaba.
Lo raro es si abro mensaje_codificado.txt con nano, ahí figura:

`^[`

osea, una tabulación con "^[" al final, y por alguna razón el texto se muestra en amarillo. ¿Exactamente cuando apareció eso ahí?
"^[" tengo entendido que es ESC, ¿pero exactamente cual de mis comandos o donde en mi programa se insertó eso?

Por cierto, estoy usando bash en gnu/linux.

**EDIT 1:**
Gran revelación

Al siguiente programa le ocurre algo interesante:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
//pruebas.cpp
int main()
{
    char c;
    while (std::cin) {
        std::cin >> c;
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

Si uso este programa de la siguiente manera también tiene un resultado (para mí) inesperado:

```
$ echo -n 'h' > asdf.txt
$ ./pruebas < asdf.txt
```

Simplemente esperaba que el resultado de esto fuera 'h' pero no lo fue, para nada, fue 'hh'. Raro. Pero parece que debe ser exactamente lo mismo que esta pasando en mi programa de cifrado.

¿Porque creo esto?

Porque si supongo que "while (std::cin)" evaluá a verdadero incluso en el segundo ciclo (que es lo que parece estar pasando en este programa) de dónde sale el ESC queda totalmente visible.
A lo que me refiero:

```
while (std::cin) {
        if (i == tamaño_llave) i = 0;
        std::cin >> c; //esto vuelve a obtener h
        c_cifrado = c^llave[i]; //acá i ahora es 1
        std::cout << c_cifrado;
        i++;
    }
```

Entonces la operación que ocurre es:

```
//recordar que llave es "asdf"
c^llave[i]
    h ^ s
    01101000
    01110011
    resultado = 11011 = 27 en decimal, ese misterioso ESC que no sabía de donde salía !
```

Ahora bien, ¿ porqué std::cin esta evaluándose a verdadero incluso después de haber consumido la 'h' con "std::cin >> c;" ? ¿ Cómo puedo evitar que ocurra eso ?

Comment: Lo que debe estar pasando es que la salida son caracteres especiales, ya que los estás imprimiendo _"en crudo"_.

Comment: ¿ La salida de "./11 asdf < mensaje_entrada.txt" te referís ? ¿Porque hacerlo así introduciría caracteres especiales? En caso que sea lo que estás diciendo ¿Cómo lo arreglo?

Comment: Los errores en `stdin` se verifican **después** de hacer la operación.  Es decir, después de intentar leer **por segunda vez** es cuando se detecta que esa segunda lectura ha fallado. Simplemente, por un `if( !std::cin ) { break; }` justo después de leer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error solo se produce cuando `cin` falla al leer. Por lo tanto, debes comprobar inmediatamente el estado de `cin`.

Cuando `cin` no puede leer correctamente, la variable `c` preserva su valor y como le permites que imprima `c` antes de verificar el error, la misma letra aparece 2 veces.

```
while (true) {
    std::cin >> c;
    if (!std::cin) break;
    std::cout << c;
}
```

O si prefieres, con un `for`:

```
for (; std::cin; std::cin >> c){
    std::cout << c;
}
```

---

Por cierto, ten en cuenta que el operador `>>` ignora los espacios en blanco. Si no te interesa que pase eso, considera usar `get`. De este modo ningún caracter será omitido:

```
c = cin.get();
```

Comment: Sos un capo!
tkm